# Tem alguma coisa de errado com esse código que envia uma String para o servidor?

Tags: java, android, servidor

Porque está dando nullPointerException.
Eu uso o OutPutStream mesmo para enviar para o servidor?

```
public void envia(String minhastring) {

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(
                "http://minhaURL");
        conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(
                conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(minhastring);
        wr.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Erro ao se conectar com o servidor");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        conn.disconnect();
    }

}
```

Quando debuguei, percebi que está com problema no url.openConnection().

Comment: Poderia postar o stack trace?

Comment: Poderia ser o protocolo, sua URL é http e voce está fazendo cast para HttpsURLConnection

Comment: David, você saber como eu posso solucionar isso?

Comment: Coloquei uma possível solução, você precisa fornecer mais informações sobre o erro...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voce pode tentar,

```
URL url = new URL( "http://minhaURL" );
HttpURLConnection conn = ( HttpURLConnection ) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-length",  minhastring.length() ); 
conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type","application/x-www- form-urlencoded" ); 
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter( conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(minhastring);
wr.flush();
```

Comment: obrigado, tava faltando o RequestProperty, agora funcionou!

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado!